# Display a warning when posting a question with long titles

Tags: feature-request, questions, title

Lately I've come across questions from (mostly) new users which use unnecessarily long titles for their questions, [such as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088047/i-bought-a-domain-name-and-a-web-hosting-on-godaddy-however-we-i-want-to-set-m):

[image]
(*Yes, that question is off-topic, but my argument still stands*)

***or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950280/saving-a-modified-image-locally-after-image-is-changed-using-client-sidejquery):***

[image]

***or perhaps [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391738/could-not-create-instance-of-type-sitecore-contentsearch-luceneprovider-analyze/26802135#26802135):***

[image]
*(could be condensed to `No matching constructor was found`; as long as [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore) is tagged, users will know what they're talking about)*

I propose a warning be shown to the user when they reach a certain amount of characters (such as 60).

Titles should be short and should briefly describe the question.

Comment: People seem to be split on this, -3/+3 votes.